# Why `-hide_banner` for `ffmpeg` is not the default?

Tags: ffmpeg

Why `-hide_banner` is not the default for `ffmpeg`? It there anything so important for every user that verbosity option `-v` can not make it?

Comment: Better suited for the bug tracker - trac.ffmpeg.org

Comment: @Gyan, password fatigue.

Comment: Here you go - https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7211

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7211#comment:1:

> `-hide_banner` is the bane of those providing help. Making it the default
>    would make providing support more difficult and less efficient. It hides
>    important and useful information.
>
> We require the user provide the full command and the complete console
>    output when they ask for help or submit a bug report. Quite often we have
>    to request this information resulting in an unnecessary delay. Making this
>    the default could result in yet another step, more information requests,
>    and more delays. We would have to explicitly mention `-show_banner` for
>    every single help request and bug report. Making `-hide_banner` the
>    default would result in more work for users and developers, frustrated
>    users, and fewer questions answered.